# Philosophy of the "fruit of the poisonous tree" doctrine

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-law, philosophy-of-political-science

I'm looking for reference works in the fields of the Philosophy of Law and Political Science on the subject of the *Fruit of the Poisonous Tree* doctrine: the view that certain products of a legal/administrative process that feed into another similar process should be excluded as input to the second process based on the manner in which the products were procured, rather than on their inherent qualities.

I'm interested in questions of rationale, purpose, legitimacy, and limitations of this doctrine, how it fits in larger legal and political frameworks, how it interacts with other values and doctrines, and in various ways in which it has manifested in various legal and administrative contexts (I'm particularly interested in the field of city planning).

Comment: This is a question of legal theory, not philosophy proper, so I doubt you'll find an answer here. You might try over on the Law stack. I mean, the basic idea (in the US at least) is that every citizen has a constitutional right to due process, which is meant to protect against oppression, harassment, summary judgement, and other tyrannical implementations of law. Officers of the court and the law cannot violate that constitutional restriction no matter how good the cause, because if they are allowed to violate it for a good cause, they will soon start violating it for bad causes.

Comment: I mean, think about civil asset forfeiture: a questionable act under the fourth amendment, but one that has still been implemented. CAF was originally intended to curb the drug trade by seizing ill-gotten wealth from dealers and suppliers — fair enough — but certain police departments now use it as a revenue stream, targeting regular citizens merely because they have asserts which can technically be seized under the letter of the law. Whatever one might think about the original goal, it's now little more than organized theft by police departments.

Comment: I'm just glad that there are still peeps like whoever thought of *the fruit of the poisonous tree* idea. Ignore the overflowing garbage bins, the litter flyin' around on the streets, air that's basically smoking 2 packsa cigarettes, and NY is beautiful, ain't it?

Comment: This is surely something for the Law Stack. It's not a topic in philosophy.

Comment: @LudwigV [I was referred to Philosophy Stack from the Law Stack](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/92433/meta-theory-of-the-fruit-of-the-poisonous-tree-doctrine?noredirect=1#comment210657_92433), though they eventually let me keep me question there, but I had already posted it here.

Comment: Well, you'll have to wait and see where you get most help. There will probably be at least one person who will try. I hope it works for you. However, the question may be closed.